# Распределение изображений в соответствующие папки по предсказанному классу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть обученная модель YOLOv8 на custom dataset. У меня есть папка со множеством изображений, мне нужно распределить все эти изображения в соответствующие папки в зависимости от их class_id. Объясните как реализовать данную задумку.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import os

model = YOLO("runs/classify/train/weights/best.pt")

image_dir = "new_images/"

results = model.predict(source=image_dir)
class_names = model.model.names

output_dirs = ["sorters/ayaka/","sorters/cutegirls/","sorters/diona/",
               "sorters/eris/","sorters/fishl/","sorters/gan_yu/",
               "sorters/hutao/","sorters/keqin/","sorters/kli/",
               "sorters/kokomi/","sorters/linnet/","sorters/lumin/",
               "sorters/mesh/","sorters/miko/","sorters/mona/",
               "sorters/nahida/","sorters/Nillu/","sorters/paimon/",
               "sorters/raiden/","sorters/shenhe/","sorters/sovmest/",
               "sorters/yoymia/",]

for output_dir in output_dirs:
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите структуру `results` для этого. Прямо в вопросе.